# mocking Completerequest() of HttpApplication class

Tags: c#

I have to unit test a method inside which following line of code is breaking:

```
m_context.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest()
```

here, `m_context` is `System.Web.HttpContext` object , which I have initialized as :-

```
var m_context= new HttpContext(new HttpRequest("", "https://www.google.com", ""), new HttpResponse(new StringWriter()));
httpContext.ApplicationInstance = new HttpApplication();
```

As `CompleteRequest()` of `HttpApplication` class is not a virtual or abstract method, can someone help me out how can I `Unittest` this scenario.

Comment: Please add a reproducible example of your test and explain what exactly are you trying to test.

Answer (score 0):

I found the following blog earlier which explains quite a nice approach using `Microsoft Moles`.
http://maraboustork.co.uk/index.php/2011/03/mocking-httpwebresponse-with-moles/

IMHO adding a functionality by extending `HttpApplication` is not the best thing to do. It is so difficult to mock the `HttpContext` because of the private/internal/sealed classes that even if you succeed your unit tests will be so cluttered with mocking code that you will no longer be able to understand what you are actually testing.